# How to reset ThinkPad T410 HDD password?

Tags: passwords

We have a few ThinkPad T410 notebooks and we don't know the HDD password for them. If we replace the HDD the notebook boots OK. Looks like the given HDD's stores the pw's?

Why? The people that used these T410 already left the company. But strangely.. they set the HDD pw to something we don't know.

**Question:** Since the notebook HDD pw cannot be reseted via battery (get it out for a week), are there any solutions for us to reset the HDD pw?

Comment: NOT TESTED!!  - check this and tell us http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Hard_Drive_Passwords

Comment: Is the user mode enabled?  If it has, then your only option, is to replace the HDDs.  The [service manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/360102/Lenovo-Thinkpad-T410s-2901.html?page=67#manual) is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The harddrives are encrypted, and you need to know the password in order to access them. This method was made to ensure the data on it is safe even if the laptop is stolen. In order to use the harddisk again, you'll need to completely format the drive which erases all data.

If that isn't an option, get in contact with the former colleagues, and ask for the password, or ask them to drop by and enter the password.

Comment: it's not encrypted imho.